# What is the word to describe trying to find the right word for something?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a "meanings" tag on English.SE, but I would like the opposite way around — I have a meaning already, I want the word (if it exists) for doing just this.

Comment: [tag:single-word-request]

Comment: @MattЭллен If that's the answer, this belongs on Meta.

Comment: Although a tag, is there also a word in a dictionary for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a *reverse lookup* and you perform it by using a [*reverse dictionary*](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a word in English for the process of searching for just the right word however the French phrase "le mot juste" is used (coined by Flaubert apparently).

Answer (score 1):

**Groping for** a word, are you?

See **grope for**, defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grope) as

> Search for (a word or answer) in one's mind.